# Range for msg_id for send.reaction?

Tags: telegram, pyrogram

How i can set a range for msg_id for sending reactions in channel? For example i want to send reaction to last 10 posts in my channel.

## Send a reaction

app.send_reaction(chat_id, message_id, "")

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to send a reaction to multiple messages at once.

You could use a `for` loop to iterate over multiple IDs to send a reaction to:

```py
for message_id in list_of_message_ids:
   app.send_reaction(chat_id, message_id, "")
```